# separating an event to perform actions in other functions depending on the result of the event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, object

Thank you for taking the time to read this. I'm learning about OOP, Module, and Constructor Function and the stuff is too advance for me so I am stuck trying to write the below code.

Im trying to separate events so I could perform  functions `addTwoNums()` and `addThreeNums()` depending on the value of what is returned from `GetAmount` I know the speek method is not set up for that. can you do something to set something like to fix it. Im so lost.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$emitter = $({})
console.log($emitter);

$("#amountItems").on('change', function(){
    var amountchosen = $("#amountItems option:selected").val();
    $emitter.trigger("amountUpdate", amountchosen);
});

var GetAmount = (function(){
    this.mode = "";
    $emitter.on("amountUpdate", function(e, val){
        if(val == 2){
            alert(2)
            this.mode = 'addTWoNumbers'
        }else if(val == 3){
            alert(3)
            this.mode = 'addThreeNumbers'
        }else if(val== 4){
            alert(4)
            this.mode = 'addFourNumbers'
        }
    })
    return  {
        speek : function(){
            console.log(this.mode);
        }

    }
})();
// I think these methods should be apart of a module
function addTwoNums(){
    GetAmount.speek(); //I guess i could instantiate an object 
  //here like (if (twonumbers = new GetAmount())) it should return addTWoNumbers 
  //so now i could do operation pertaining to 2 numbers
    //do some function when 2 is chosen
}

function addThreeNums(){
    //do some function when 3 is chosen
}

});
```

Also I got that part `$emitter = $({})` from another source but I would like a clearfiacation on how it works. because where making `$emitter` an empty 
jquery obj that mean we could use it for some type of place holder to trigger events. its like were making up an object just to perform actions on it but it doesnt contain anything.

I know these concepts are from pub/sub type of pattern.I think I'm trying to make a pub/sub.

HTML:

```
<div class="select labelOuter">
    <!-- <p>How many Items would you like to add</p> -->
    <select name="" id="amountItems" data-chosen ="0">
        <option selected default disabled value="">Amount of items</option>
        <option  value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>

    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the syntax error?

Comment: You shouldn't have `:` after `return`.

Comment: @Barmar Aha of course :-).